# the usage of the apostrophe

Tags: word-usage, apostrophe

Which is more correct to say: **in todays' classes** or in **today's classes**?
Can we consider that **today** represents the days that we live in general, so it might be considered as plural, and add the apostrophe after the s and not before?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the classes literally only today, this one 24-hour period, it's singular: *today's classes*. If you're talking more abstractly, as in "*kids these days*", it suppose it *might* be defensible to use the plural: *todays' kids*. Though that still seems odd at first blush. Safer to go with the singular.

Answer (score 2):

**today's**

Even if you use the word *today* to mean *nowadays*, it is still singular. You cen prove it by doing the following mental exercise:

> Today's TV programs are horrible.
>
> The TV programs of today are horrible.
>
> <strike>The TV programs of todays are horrible.</strike>